# Swift 2.1 broke ZCarousel; Array of strings

Tags: ios, arrays, swift2

I just updated Xcode and my code is broken. I am using ZCarousel and this code works great for Swift 2.0:

```
var buttonsArray: Array = ["Track ONE(1)", "Track TWO(2)", "Track THREE(3)", "Track FOUR(4)", "Track FIVE(5)"]

menu = ZCarousel(frame: CGRect( x: self.view.frame.size.width/5, y: 40, width: (self.view.frame.size.width/5)*3, height: 50))
    menu.ZCdelegate = self
    menu.addButtons(buttonsArray)
```

Swift 2.1 now I get an error message:

```
menu.addButtons(buttonsArray)
```

Cannot convert value of type 'Array' to expected argument type '[String]'
I can't find anything on this. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete the type declaration:

```
 var buttonsArray = // ....
```

The problem is not ZCarousel; your `Array` declaration was always wrong (I'm surprised it ever compiled).

Comment: Thank you, that was it. Something so simple. After I read your answer I did a little research. I am not sure why it worked before, but not now. Thanks again!!